# Chinese characters are getting to junk characters - Progress4gL - Open edge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Program language - open Edge, progress4GL

Looking for your help, while reading Chinese characters from XML file, they are getting converted to junk characters.

The XML file is UTF-8 encoded.

Session we are loading XML has code page = “ISO8859-1”

Already tried using MEMPTR variable but no success, can anyone advise what can be done to resolve this?

```
INPUT FROM value (cFileName) BINARY NO-MAP no-convert.
  IMPORT unformatted mPointer.
INPUT CLOSE.    

SET-SIZE(mPointer) = mPointerSize.     

CREATE X-DOCUMENT hXML .
hXML:ENCODING = "UTF-8".

CREATE X-NODEREF  hRoot.

hXML:LOAD("memptr",mPointer,FALSE)  NO-ERROR.
```

Answer (score 4):

iso8859-1 cannot display Chinese characters.  You need to match up your session code page with the data that you are reading.  The obvious solution would be to start your session with the relevant -cp* parameters set to utf8.  **HOWEVER** -- it is extremely important to make sure that this is compatible with whatever your database is using for a code pages (-cpinternal) if you use incompatible code pages to store data you are going to corrupt the db.  Garbage in, garbage out...

The following article is a reasonable start:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P762

So the **first** thing that you need to do is to figure out what code page your db is running with.

You can reliably discover this in a platform neutral way by looking at dbname.lg and searching for "-cpinternal" or "(4264)".

But be very careful -- as I mentioned above if you force an incompatible conversion you risk corrupting your database.  If the db was not created with support for utf8 (or another code page compatible with Chinese characters) you must first fix that problem.